# I can't create maven project with myeclipse2016

Tags: maven, myeclipse

I got into trouble. Who can help me, thank you. 
I want to create a maven project for web. I new the web project and pick up ***Add maven support***, but it is stuck on the ***Configure Maven Dependencies***. I don't know the cause of the problem. 
The IDE is MyEclipse 2016 and JDK1.8.

Comment: I didn't use myeclipse before, but I believe you can create a maven web project using archetype (maven project templating tool), and then import that project to MyEclipse. Please follow this link to generate the project template: https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/